# Gray out a day in Sharepoint calendar

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-designer

I've been trying to grayout a day in sharepoint calendar using the script editor. What I need is to be able grayout specific days e.g. Christmas day. I found an article the uses the below code to gray out every weekend but I need to be able to select a specific day rather than every....

P.S I haven't test the below so not sure if it works, thanks in advance guys!

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-day6{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.ms-acal-day0{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grayout one day header will be simple.

Demo:

```
<style>
td[date="12/25/2019"]
{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
```

[image]

While if you want to Grayout the FULL grid cell, it will be more complex, you could inject custom logic for calendar render to check the month and add/remove CSS dynamically.

```
<style>
        td[date="12/25/2019"] {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeCalendarEvents, "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
        function CustomizeCalendarEvents() {
            //Month Calendar View
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids_Old =
                SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids;
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids =
                function SP_UI_ApplicationPages_SummaryCalendarView$renderGrids($p0) {
                    this.renderGrids_Old($p0);
                    //alert(document.getElementById("WPQ2_nav_header").innerText);
                    if (document.getElementById("WPQ2_nav_header").innerText == "December 2019") {
                        var css = 'table.ms-acal-month tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(4){background-color: #CCCCCC;}',
                            head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                            style = document.createElement('style');

                        head.appendChild(style);

                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.title = 'MSCustom';
                        if (style.styleSheet) {
                            // This is required for IE8 and below.
                            style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                        } else {
                            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('style[title="MSCustom"]').remove();                           
                    }
                };
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks for providing this. It seems to work as intended but may I ask if it's possible to make the date as a range of days e.g. from the 25th of December 2019 to the 10th of January 2020? Thanks in advance!